# Angular5 inject HTML content from child component into another component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components

Not sure if this is possible but I have a reusable header section that gets data from the route data property. This displays a title and description inside the header.

My question is that depending on the route I'm in, how do I inject in different HTML content into the header? I know that you can use ng-content but that would require the header section to be placed in every component. The header sits outside of the main router outlet

This is the positioning of the header in relation to the router outlet

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-header></app-header>
<app-alert></app-alert>
<router-outlet #route="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

This is the header

```
<div class="title">
  <div class="title-text">
    <h1>{{ data?.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ data?.description }}</p>
  </div>
  <ng-content>Here is where I would like to inject HTML from child component</ng-content
</div>
```

And this is what I would like to inject in

```
  <label class="select" for="product-selection">Products</label>
  <select class="select" id="product-selection" placeholder="Product" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct" (change)="onProductChanged()">
    <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id">{{ product.name }}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: have you try `@input` and `@outpout`, you can handle data as event

Answer (score 0):

if the header sits outside of the main router outlet then you would have to use create a global variable in service and using *ngIF directive you can show the required headrer.

Steps to implement this :
1) Fetch the value from router and save in the service global varible.
2) Use that variable in the header component with *ngIf and show the header value.